# Laravel Download Remote file

Tags: php, download, laravel-5, twilio, twilio-php

I am using `Laravel` with `Twilio`. One of the features that `Twilio` offers is the ability to `download recordings of conversations`.

I thought to save the recording URL in the database for streaming purposes and then whenever someone wants to access the raw file of the recording I would allow them to download it at will and pass it through from Twilio just so that I don't have to store media that Twilio is already storing.

I am finding however that trying to download a file with Laravel by just passing through the remote URL is not possible. I am not trying to create a whole new storage driver like `s3` or `rackspace`, the goal is just to take the full url path to the remote file, fetch it, and then immediately serve it when the download button is clicked.

I've tried to use the `response()->download()` method but that seems to only work with the local filesystem.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Simply _link_ to the download URL the API provides you with …?

Comment: Wouldn't that automatically stream it and not download it?

Comment: If it deserves the name “download link” (sets the right HTTP headers to force a download), then not.

Comment: @CBroe please answer the file properly so I can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ricky from Twilio here.

To force a download, you can just append `?Download=true` to the [Recording Instance URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-get-wav) you've stored in your database. For example:

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Recordings/{RecordingSid}.wav?Download=true

Whenever a user clicks a link with that url they will start downloading the recording.

Hope that helps!